# BitBucket Pipeline :: Reset default test result directory/file path to fix the test result count

Tags: continuous-integration, testng, bitbucket

The maven build is giving correct results on local, but I run the same through bit bucket pipeline, in the end the test result of build section is giving test result count 3 times of the total. I found the similar problem posted over the atlassian platform but with no answer::

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-Pipelines-questions/Test-count-is-coming-wrong/qaq-p/1269060

I saw the post build section and noticed default the test result parser is parsing each of the test xml file in the surefire/failsafe/test-results folder and that is why count is incorrect.

I tried to reset the default test result directory/file path in bitbucket pipeline file, but found a solution for GitLab but not for the Bitbucket:

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/test-reporting-in-pipelines/

Answer (score 0):

So was waiting for last 2 month to find configuration level solution but I have to choose a workaround.

I deleted directory under target i.e junitresults and the suite named folder before the bitbucket tear down phase.

Since my project is testng+maven , so I used IsuiteListener and maven clean plugin to clean directory casuing duplicate test results.

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Deleting all unnecessary files</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>target/surefire-reports/junitreports</directory>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And For suite level folder

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator 
+ "target" + File.separator + "surefire-reports"
            + File.separator + "${suite folder name}";
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(path));
            MainLogger.logger().info("deleted " + path);
        } else
            MainLogger.logger().info("Not deleted " + path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```